# How to make child elements of jQuery .resizable move on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a JQuery resizable to add a social option to my site and I need two images to move in the direction that the re size is taking place. Right now the re-size works is just that my two social images never move and act as if they're fix to the document.

**--HTML**

```
<div id="joinSocial" class="rcRT rcRB joinSocial ui-resizable" style="position: absolute; top: 407px; left: 0px; width: 76.72000026702881px;">

<img id="imgLk" src="/imgs/social/linkedin50x50.gif">
<img id="imgTw" src="/imgs/social/twitter50x50.gif">

<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>

</div>
```

**--CSS**

```
.joinSocial {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    width: 65px;
    height:125px !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 25000;
    padding: .5em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.joinSocial img {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.rcRT {
    border: 1px solid #c1bebe;
    -moz-border-radius-topRight: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.rcRB {
    border: 1px solid #c1bebe;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomRight: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

**--JavaScript**

```
setTimeout(function() {

    var joinSocial = docCreateAttrs('div',{id:'joinSocial','class':'rcRT rcRB joinSocial',title:'Join the AlumCloud social network.'}),
        imgLk= docCreateAttrs('img',{id:'imgLk',src:'/imgs/social/linkedin50x50.gif'}),
        imgtw= docCreateAttrs('img',{id:'imgTw', src:'/imgs/social/twitter50x50.gif'});

    document.body.appendChild(joinSocial.addChilds([imgLk,imgtw]));

    $(joinSocial).resizable(
        {
            handles: "e"
        });
},1000);
```

**--Before and after resize**

[image: Before and after resize]

I need for the images to slide into the left portion of the viewport and hide like it's parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waite, what means hide? Do you mean resize to fit width, or you mean when the div to a trigger point, the image would be hided?

If you mean resize to fit width:

```
<img id="imgLk" src="/imgs/social/linkedin50x50.gif" width="100%">
<img id="imgTw" src="/imgs/social/twitter50x50.gif" width="100%">
```

CSS

```
.joinSocial img {
    display:block;
}
```

If you mean div resize trigger a point which would hide images, please read : http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize

You need use, I may put bug in, please understand the idea behind it:

```
$(joinSocial).resizable({
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
        if( ui.size.width < 20 ){ // the width you looking for
              $('#imgLk,#imgTw').hide();
        }else{
              $('#imgLk,#imgTw').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would like the div to a trigger point, the image would be hided?